# Perl Error: Attempt to bless into a reference

Tags: perl, oop

I have been working with OO Perl. I have base class, which is legacy code and I can't change it. I am writing a derived class with a new style (my convenient style too) but when I am deriving it I am getting an error as

```
Attempt to bless into a reference
```

My code is similar to the below code:

```
 package Base ;
   sub new {
        my ($class, %args) = @_;
        my $self = {};
    
        $self->{top} = $args{top};
        return bless $self, $class;
    }
1;
```

The Derived class:

```
package derived;
use base qw{Base};
use  fields qw{_bot};

sub new {

    my __PACKAGE__ $this = shift;
    my %arg = @_;
    
    unless (ref $this) {
        $this = fields::new($this);

    }
    $this->Base::new( %arg);
    return $this;
}
1;
```

The caller is

```
use File::Basename;
BEGIN {
  my $root_dir = dirname $0;
  push(@INC, $root_dir);
}
use derived;
my $d = new derived(top=>"t1");
```

I am getting error as

```
Attempt to bless into a reference at Base.pm line 8.
```

Comment: Try to use `my $self = Base->new(...)` instead of `$this->Base::new(...)`

Comment: You didn't follow fields.pm's docs. If you're going to use fields.pm, you will need to use it as instructed.

Comment: I think you need to use `fields` pragma in both `Base` and `derived`, now you're only use it in `derived`. Since you can't change the code in `Base` (you said so) and it is not using `fields` currently, I am not sure if you can use `fields` in `derived`

Comment: Thanks all i got it and decided to write in old style

Comment: I believe you can use fields.pm in a subclass even if the base class doesn't, but you would have to list all the fields the base class creates because fields.pm "locks" the hash to making it impossible to access undeclared fields. That won't help here, though, because the base class would still have to use the hash created in the derived class instead of creating a new one, just like the docs for fields.pm shows.